# Will it start rolling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Suppose you have a wheel standing stationary on a rough horizontal surface. Now you apply a horizontal force at the top of the wheel. Now, will the wheel experience any force or will it just start rolling smoothly?

I am a beginner to physics and hence, slightly confused. Please help

Comment: The wheel will experience a torque when the horizontal force is applied and it will roll and eventually stop.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ friction is being applied in direction of F. Direction, now, has no significance as $f$ will come out to be negative if it is opposite direction.

$$F+f=ma$$
$$FR-fR=I\alpha$$
symbols have their usual meanings

Note that if pure rolling occurs, $f$ is static.
Also, 
$$a=\alpha R$$

You can calculate $f$. If
$$|f|> \mu_{static}mg$$

You can conclude that there will be no pure rolling, $f$ will be maximum and $$a\neq \alpha R $$

Otherwise pure rolling occurs.